# kubeflow AttributeError: 'ComponentStore' object has no attribute 'uri_search_template'

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to load some prebuit gcp kubeflow components using `kfp.components.ComponentStore`. However I am getting this error:

```
line 180, in _load_component_spec_in_component_ref
    if self.uri_search_template:
AttributeError: 'ComponentStore' object has no attribute 'uri_search_template'
```

when at this line of code:

```
mlengine_train_op = component_store.load_component('ml_engine/train')
```

KFP version:

```
kfp                             1.8.10
kfp-pipeline-spec               0.1.13
kfp-server-api                  1.7.1
```

Steps to reproduce

```
import kfp
from kfp.components import func_to_container_op

COMPONENT_URL_SEARCH_PREFIX = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubeflow/pipelines/1.7.1/components/gcp/"

component_store = kfp.components.ComponentStore(
    local_search_paths=None, url_search_prefixes=[COMPONENT_URL_SEARCH_PREFIX])

mlengine_train_op = component_store.load_component('ml_engine/train')
mlengine_deploy_op = component_store.load_component('ml_engine/deploy')
```

I got this code from an example that was running on kfp `0.2.5`. This is probably some version problem but does anyone knows how to update this code to the newer version?

Comment: Can you try passing a non-empty string to the `uri_search_template` parameter? That seemed to not throw any error. I'm not sure about the reason for the behaviour.

Comment: It does seem like a bug or as you said we might need a new sample. Found the [Github issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/7220) you had created. Posting it here for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. It is something that @Kabilan Mohanraj also mentioned is his comment. It looks like there is a bug if you don't set up uri_search_template when creating the ComponentStore.
I solved it by providing it as parameter, it doesn't really matter what you pass to the constructor really, but it is required because in the code there is the following

```
if self.url_search_prefixes:
```

but if you don't pass something that attribute doesn't get created in the constructor.
I fixed it like this:

```
component_store = kfp.components.ComponentStore(
    local_search_paths=["local_search_path"], url_search_prefixes=[COMPONENT_URL_SEARCH_PREFIX]), uri_search_template="{name}/"
```

I hope it will help someone in the future.
I suggested in the github issue to address this by either make the error more clear or to have better check on uri_search_template attribute.